# How to return to previous value in dictionary given a specific value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have different tax rates for different income levels.

I am trying to return the previous tax rate from the tax rate acquired from a function. How can I get it to return to the previous tax rate?

```
tax_levels = [
{
    "min": 0,
    "max": 999,
    "rate": 1,
},
{
    "min": 1000,
    "max": 1999,
    "rate": 5
},
]

current_rate = 5
previous_rate = ??
```

I am trying to get it to return to 1 for previous_rate using the variable current_rate.

Comment: do you previous on list ? use for-loop to find `rate: 5` and you should get its index (position on list) and then you get `tax_levels[index-1]['rate']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function

```py
def previous_tax_rate(current_rate, tax_levels):
    for index, tax_level in enumerate(tax_levels):
        if tax_level['rate'] == current_rate:
            return tax_levels[index - 1]['rate']
```

Comment: do you know how can you can get in to return to "1999"? the "max" value.

Comment: @lssee instead of `tax_levels[index - 1]['rate']` do `tax_levels[index - 1]['max']`

Answer (score 0):

```
tax_level[0]['rate']
```

tax_level is a list containing dictionaries.
tax_level[0] will give you the first dictionary in the list.
['rate'] will give you the value of the key 'rate' in the first dictionary in the tax_level list of dictionaries.